# read and print file contents with nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

hello I'm using docker and ansible to launch a container which will then launch a server.js file, which needs to display the contents of an index.html file located in the same directory. I have this skeleton outline code which works in displaying "Hello World" to the screen when I curl the ip address running this server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response)
{
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server started');
```

the console.log does not display on the screen, seemingly only response.end does that, with printing 'Hello World' to the screen, so I've been trying to read in the index.html file as a variable and have response.end display it but with no luck.

I tried doing this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response)
{
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

var fs = require('fs');
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('index.html');
readStream.pipe(response); 

//response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server started');
```

but when I tried to curl it it resulted in a an Error 52 empty reply from the server, am I not doing enough to read in my index.html file and store it as a string variable? thanks.

Comment: Any errors in the Node console?

Comment: https://imgur.com/P7lVKi2

Comment: do i need to include error handling?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
 fs.readFile("index.html","utf8" ,function(err, contents){
 console.log(contents);
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
 res.write(contents);
 res.end();
 });
}).listen(3000);

if you want to show the contents of the file on  request to the server try this.
```